# Custom Image Shear layer in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, keras-layer

Im migrating from Keras's ImageDataGenerators to tf.data and I have issues with reproducing the same augmentation I used to have in generator. While there are regularization layers for Random Zoom, Random Rotation or Random Flip in tf.keras, there is none for Shear transformation.

I am trying to write a custom layer using tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear. I know that some image-related functions do not work with batches (random_shear included), so I use the map_fn:

```
class Shear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    '''
    Define tf.keras.layer which randomly shears the input images.
    The layer is active only during inference
    '''
    def __init__(self, factor = 30, **kwargs):
        '''
        Initialize the Shear layer
        
        param factor: intensity of transformation in degrees
        '''
        
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.factor = factor
        
    def shear(self, image):
        '''
        Randomly shear a single image 
        '''
        
        return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(image, self.factor, 0, 1, 2) #channels last
        
    def call(self, x, training = None):
        '''
        Randomly shear a batch of images 
        '''
        
        if not training:
            return x

        return tf.map_fn(self.shear, x)
```

The layer itself works: I transformed and visualized some batches with it, and the result is as expected. However, when I connect this layer to model, during training on GPU I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
return step_function(self, iterator)
train.py:72 shear  *
  return tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(image, self.factor, 0, 1, 2)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:115 random_shear  *
x = apply_affine_transform(x, shear=shear, channel_axis=channel_axis,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:327 apply_affine_transform  *
channel_images = [ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:520 __iter__
self._disallow_iteration()
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:513 _disallow_iteration
 self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:491 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
      " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))

 OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

I tried to enable numpy behaviour, but it didn't help. I tried to apply shear transform inside tf.data pipeline, but for some reason I can't map shear function on batches + I'd like to have all preprocessing inside the model as layers. I'd use shear_x/shear_y functions from tfa.image, but they don't have proper filling modes.

I created similar layers with tf.image functions, such as random_jpeg_quality, and they work just fine, but when I use something outside of tf.image, I get errors :(

Will be thankful for any suggestions about resolving this issue

P. S. I use TF 2.5.0

Comment: Tensorflow Addons has a [`shear_x`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/shear_x) and a [`shear_y`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/shear_y) implementation that perhaps you could combine to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As I stated in the original question, those tfa functions do not have proper fill modes (reflect, nearest etc). Instead, they force you to replace empty pixels with a constant value. Implementing desired functions from scratch is indeed a possibility, but I'd like to have a consistent way of using pre-existing preprocessing functions (not only shear) in custom layers or at least get an idea why some of them work (jpeg quality, for example) and some do not.